# Using netty with 3rd party blocking API

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty

I am using a 3rd party blocking API. I am going to be using this API as follows:

```
while(true){
blockingAPI();
sendResultSomewhere();
}
```

`blockingAPI()` polls a server for a specific property until it gets a response.

In order to make things asynchronous to some extent I could spawn this API call within a separate thread. and have a callback implemented in Java to handle the response. I was wondering if I can use the netty framework in this scenario, and how I could do this? The examples I have seen involve a server that listens and communicates with a client, and I am not sure how my use case fits in.

If netty cannot be used, would my best bet be spawning a new thread and implementing a callback in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really try to do:

1. Spawn internally a new thread: you could use LocalChannel with Netty to have intra-JVM process communication and therefore having something like you want, without any network consideration (only within the JVM). The blockingAPI will be computed within ServerLocalChannel side, while the result will be written once the client get back a response through the same LocalChannel.
2. Spawn but with a request from outside (network), then Netty could of course be used too there. Maybe still keeping a LocalChannel logic to separate network to compute.

Note that I could recommand to use asynchronous operation using LocalChannel (executing the blocking task), such that the send somewhere else is done without blocking the Netty's Network IO thread.

Network Handler side:

```
localChannel = creationWithinNetworkHandler(networkChannelCtx);
localChannel.writeAndFlush(something);
```

while LocalChannel handler server side could be as:

```
void read0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, someData) {
  blockingAPI();
  ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(answear).addFutureListener(Channels.CloseFuture);
}
```

and LocalChannel handler client side could be as:

```
void read0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, answear) {
  //Using ctx from Network channel side
  networkCtx.writeAndFlush(answear);
}
```